# Can Kerberos (klist) show two tickets from the same principal?

Tags: kerberos

I'm attempting to write a script that checks whether my Kerberos tickets are valid or expiring soon.  To do this, I use `klist --json` or `klist` to produce a list of currently active tickets (depending on version of Kerberos installed), then I parse the results with regular expressions or JSON.

The end result is that I get a list of tickets that looks like this:

```
  Issued                Expires               Principal
Aug 19 16:44:51 2020  Aug 22 14:16:55 2020  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
Aug 20 09:05:06 2020  Aug 20 19:05:06 2020  ldap/abc-dc101.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
Aug 20 09:32:18 2020  Aug 20 19:32:18 2020  krbtgt/DEV.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
```

With a little bit of work, I can parse these results and verify them.  However I'm curious whether it's ever possible that Kerberos will have two tickets from the same principal.  Reading  [the MIT page on Kerberos usage](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/tkt_mgmt.html) it seems like there is only ever one ticket that would be the "initial" ticket.

Can I rely on uniqueness by principal, or do I need to check for the possibility of multiple tickets from the same principal?

Comment: Short answer: grab the default realm from `/etc/krb5.conf` then match the entry with `krbtgt/DEF.REALM@DEF.REALM$` (and bonus points if you escape the dot properly in the realm name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that.
**TL;DR** Your 2nd TGT seems related to cross-realm authentication, see below in bold.

`klist` shows the tickets that are present in the default system cache:

- error message if there is no such cache to query *(i.e. `FILE` cache that does not exist, `KEYRING` kernel service not started, etc)*
- possibly 1 TGT (Ticket Granting Ticket) that asserts your identity in your own realm
- possibly N service tickets that assert you are entitled to contact service X on server Z (which may belong to another realm, see below)
- in the case of **cross-realm authentication**, some intermediate tickets that allow you to convert your TGT in realm `A.R` to a TGT in realm `R` that allows you to get a service ticket in realm `B.R` *(that would be the default, hierarchical path used with e.g. Active Directory but custom paths may be defined in `/etc/krb5.conf` under `[capath]` or sthg like that, depending on the trusts defined between realms)*

But note that not all service tickets are stored in the cache -- it is legit for an app to get the TGT from the cache, get a service ticket, and keep it private in memory. That's what Java does.

And it is legit for an app (or group of apps) to use a private cache, cf. env variable `KRB5CCNAME` (pretty useful when you have multiple services running under the same Linux account and don't want to mix up their SPN) so you can't see their tickets with `klist` unless you tap this custom cache explicitly.

And it is legit for an app to not use the cache at all, and keep all its tickets private in memory. That's what Java does when provided with a custom JAAS config that mandates to authenticate with principal/keytab.

Comment: Thanks for these details!  I wrote my code to assume that there will only ever be a maximum of one ticket per principal.  In practice, my experience is that the initial ticket generally is renewable and the secondary tickets tend to expire over time.  I was able to detect renewal situations by observing whether the initial ticket is close to expiration, or whether any secondary tickets are expired. This has worked well for me.